# Git. Создать новый начальный коммит

Tags: git

Иногда бывает нужно создать коммит без предка и начать всю историю заново, перетащив rebase'ом туда часть старых коммитов. Просто rebase не позволяет изменять первый коммит.

Пока придумал два способа:

1. Создать новый репозиторий и подключить его как remote. У каждого из них будет свой начальный коммит.
2. Создать новую ветку на первом коммите и ammend'ом изменить его до неузнаваемости.

Может есть и другие способы? Проще или интереснее.

PS Я знаю, что это совсем не стандартный способ использования.

PPS На всякий случай напоминаю, что исправлять уже опубликованную историю - это моветон.

Comment: `git checkout --orphan <new_branch>`. [`--orphan <new_branch>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---orphanltnewbranchgt): Create a new *orphan* branch, named <new_branch>, started from <start_point> and switch to it. The first commit made on this new branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.

Comment: `и начать всю историю заново` ......`исправлять уже опубликованную историю - это моветон.` ... что-то не вяжется тут

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, все вяжется. Репозиторий с длинной историей, но ни разу не публиковался.

Comment: *Просто `rebase` не позволяет...* — **позволяет**! Читайте документацию. Ваш вариант `git rebase --interactive --root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в том же самом репозитории создать новую ветку с параметром `--orphan`

```
git checkout --orphan имя_ветки

git reset --mixed  # текущее состояние репозитория оказывается в индексе,
                   # поэтому сбрасываем его; теперь в рабочем каталоге нету
                   # файлов под версионным контролем
```

Далее можно выбрать нужные вам файлы командой `git add` и сделать фиксацию без родителей с помощью `git commit`.

---

Ещё один довольно забавный способ начать историю заново — создать новый пустой репозиторий, затем синхронизироваться со старым и вытащить только нужные файлы нужных версий. Вот мой пример.

```
$ dir  # в исходной репе есть 1 файл
poem.txt
$ git log --oneline  # и 4 фиксации
620e259 lines 9..14
29621bb lines 4..8
7e92659 lines 2..3
3a1c273 line 1
$ pushd ../t2  # (cd ../t2)
/tmp/tmp.8mCcg7urEJ/t2 /tmp/tmp.8mCcg7urEJ/t1
$ git init  # создаём новый репозиторий в пустой папке
$ git fetch ../t1  # тут можно было бы указать URL
$ git checkout 7e92659 poem.txt  # забираем файл нужной версии
$ cat poem.txt  # вот он
Мой дядя самых честных правил,
Когда не в шутку занемог,
Он уважать себя заставил
$ git commit -m 'cloned lines'  # фиксируем его как нам надо
$ git cherry-pick 29621bb  # пытаемся применить ещё какую-либо фиксацию
$ cat poem.txt  # новое содержимое, уже зафиксированное
Мой дядя самых честных правил,
Когда не в шутку занемог,
Он уважать себя заставил
И лучше выдумать не мог;
Его пример другим наука;
Но, Боже мой, какая скука
С больным сидеть и день и ночь,
Не отходя ни шагу прочь!
$ git log --oneline  # тут в итоге получилось две фиксации
939567a lines 4..8
63b3e02 cloned lines
```

Comment: `git checkout --orphan` - именно то, что я искал, спасибо. Раз есть такая команда, значит я не один такой извращенец :)

Comment: `git reset --mixed` - не совсем понятно. Мы либо откатываемся до указанного коммита, либо меняем текущий. Мне кажется, что это тот же способ что и у меня под номером 2.

Comment: "создать новый пустой репозиторий" - это вариация моего первого способа.

Comment: После выполнения `git checkout --orphan` никаких новых фиксаций не появляется, просто текущее состояние репозитория целиком оказывается в индексе (можно убедиться с помощью `git status`). По идее есть возможность не очищать индекс целиком, а выкинуть только отдельные файлы командой `git rm`.

Comment: @0andriy, не могли бы пояснить, что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @0andriy, вероятно, вам стоит это оформить как настоящий ответ в виде полноценного сообщения