# Цвет линий веток в git log graph?

Tags: git, git-bash

Настройки git config --global --list ,
параметры в конфиге для цвета не указаны!!!

Вопрос, почему линии выводятся красным одним цветом (до слияния), ведь ветвей две? так и должно быть? или до слияния это нормальное поведение? хотя если посмотреть в git lens настройке для vs code на граф, то там до слияния ветки показываются разными цветами!!!

После слияния ветвей цветов линий уже становится две (красный и зеленый)!
И если можно объяснить не совсем понимаю после слияния, что означают вот эти вертикальные линии? (это идет ветвь от родительского коммита * c9938db ?) вправо / продолжается  а потом вверх | 88d0e8a второй коммит на мастер ? :
вот этот участок не совсем понимаю??
[image: участок графа для прояснения]

и не совсем понятно, что означает одна единичная красная вертикальная черта в последнем выводе?
git log --oneline -all --graph --date-order ?

это в git bash в vs code!!!
git init

1. создали файл file1.txt
2. добавили в индекс
3. сделали коммит
   git commit -m "Initial commit in master"
4. создали ветку add-fall-menu
5. в ней создали два file2.txt и file3.txt
   git commit - m "Add file2.txt in add-fall-menu"
   git commit -m "Add file3.txt in add-fall-menu"
6. переключились на master изменили file1.txt добавили в индекс и закоммитили
   git commit -m "Add changes in file1.txt in master"

git log --oneline --all --graph (до слияния)

[image: Вывод git log --oneline --all --graph]
git log --oneline --all --graph (после слияния)
[image: git log --oneline --all --graph после слияния]

git log --oneline --all --graph --date-order (после слияния)
[image: git log --oneline --all --graph --date-order (после слияния)]

Comment: «что означает одна единичная красная вертикальная черта» — только то, что эти коммиты соединены отношением предок-потомок, больше ничего

Answer (score 0):

Это "дерево" коммитов.  Но на самом деле это не дерево. ))
У коммита может быть 1 или 2 предка (снизу) и от 0 до бесконечности потомков (сверху).  Да, бывают октомёржи с 3+ предками, но их редко используют.  В коментах дополнили, что бывают коммиты-сиротки с 0 родителей (но тогда это уже совсем не дерево коммитов получается, а лес коммитов).
По-простому:
Слева идёт "пучок проводов", текст справа соответствует тому пучку, на котором звёздочка, остальные "провода" просто мимокрокодилы.
А цвета выбираются без какой-либо полезной логики - в них нет смысла (я об этом как-то [спрашивал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675151/what-do-line-colors-in-git-log-graph-mean)).

Comment: У коммита может быть и 0 предков. И не только у первого (я об этом как-то спрашивал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707325 :)

Comment: @ГерманБорисов - дополнил про сирот